# How to I make one row/segment of a table change when I hover over another row/segment?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 2 tables on my [site](http://school.shad0w.tk).

I want to make it so that when I hover over the producer ID in the first table, it changes the colour of the producer ID row in the 2nd table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to use some simple javascript events.

Pure JS:

```
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0];
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0];

one.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    two.classList.toggle("red");
});

one.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    two.classList.toggle("red");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zv9r7oL2/1/

This is made even easier with jQuery:

```
$(".one").hover(function() {
    $(".two").toggleClass('red');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zv9r7oL2/

Same with tables:
https://jsfiddle.net/zv9r7oL2/2/

Edit:
Also, such events should be handled after the document is fully loaded. 
So for pure JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
 //put all your code here
}
```

for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//your code here
}
```

And dont forget to link the jQuery library to use it :) add this to your < head > html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, of course, since it relies on css classes and not anything else.
Also, you can just add events to any DOM element you like, so in jQuery it would look like this for example 
$("#producer-id-1").hover( function() {
    $("#producer-id-2").toggleClass("red");
}

you just have to work out the logic of your specific case.

Comment: edited with table example. Maybe i'm not understanding your task correctly?

Comment: Tried both, including putting a div in the table. [This](http://school.shadow.tk/low_stock.php) is the table I'm working on

Comment: Appended some info to my answer. Also, your link isn't working for me.

Comment: Seems like you are using jQuery, but forgot to include it in your document.

Comment: add this to <head></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: you didn't close your .hover function at the end there, mate  " }); "

Comment: added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, use developer console to easily see all the errors, f12 in chrome

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark as answer and upvote :)

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day.